# Finding maximum value of the given trigonometric expression after simplification

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

If $\theta$ $\in \matrix{\left[\frac{-5\pi}{12},\frac{-\pi}{3}\right]}$ then find maximum value of:

[image]

---

Initally, I went on with calculating the derivative which came out to be:

$$\frac{\left(\sec^{2}\left(\theta+\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)-\sec^{2}\left(\theta+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)-\sin\left(\theta+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{3}}$$

This seemed pretty hard to work with in order to equate it to 0 and then proceed with the general method of finding maxima/minima.  So I thought maybe simplifying the given expression and then taking the derivative would make this more simple.
I came up with the following simplified version of it(the original expression given in the problem):

$$\tan\left(\theta+\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)=-\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-\theta\right)$$
and  $$\tan\left(\theta+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-\theta\right)$$
and $$\cos\left(\theta+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-\theta\right)$$

Hence,  $$\frac{\left(-\left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-\theta\right)+\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-\theta\right)\right)+\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-\theta\right)\right)}{\sqrt{3}}$$

getting the same argument in each trigonometric function, I thought, would help out. But I still can't really get something after differentiating it:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(\sec ^2\left(\frac{\pi }{3}-x\right)-\csc ^2\left(\frac{\pi }{3}-x\right)-\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{3}-x\right)\right)$$

I think this is just about rearranging the trigonometric terms but I'm not able to get to it, please help me out with this, or if there's any other method.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the $\sqrt{3}$.
It obviously doesn't matter
except for the final value
of the extrema.

You then have
for the derivative

$\begin{array}\\
g(x)
&=-(\tan(\frac{\pi}{3}-x)+\cot(\frac{\pi}{3}-x))+\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}-x))\\
&=-(\tan(y)+\cot(y)+\sin(y))
\qquad y = \frac{\pi}{3}-x\\
&=-(\dfrac{\sin(y)}{\cos(y)}+\dfrac{\cos(y)}{\sin(y)}+\sin(y))
\qquad y = \frac{\pi}{3}-x\\
&=-(\dfrac{\sin^2(y)+\cos^2(y)}{\sin(y)\cos(y)}+\sin(y))\\
&=-(\dfrac{1+\sin^2(y)\cos(y)}{\sin(y)\cos(y)})\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$|\sin^2(y)\cos(y)|
\le \dfrac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}
\lt 1$,
the derivative has
no real root,
so the function has
its extrema at the endpoints.

Comment: Please clarify this since, I am a bit confused. $g(x)$ is the function itself and not the derivative right?( since you've written 'You then have for the derivative' . Also, can you please elaborate more on how we can conclude that the derivative has no real roots? This indeed leads to the result that's given in my book but I couldn't understand these parts. Thanks in advance!